# Matching user's password with hashed password stored in DB

Tags: php

Somebody should pls guide me on how i can fetch out hashed password from database and match the password entered by a user when login in 
i used php crypt() function with bcrypt algorithms to hash the password when registrian the user
thank you all in advance

Comment: The docs provide an example of this http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: hash the user input password again and then match it with the one in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php):

```
$hashed_password = crypt('mypassword'); // let the salt be automatically generated
if (crypt($user_input, $hashed_password) == $hashed_password) {
   echo "Password verified!";
}
```

You need to pass in the original hash, otherwise crypt will generate a random salt and the passwords are very unlikely to match. I.e.

```
//BROKEN - will almost always print "Bugger off!".
$hash = crypt('Hello world');
$attempt = crypt('Hello world');
if($hash === $attempt){
    echo "Access granted!";
}else{
    echo "Bugger off!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just send the unencrypted password into the same crypt process as you did with the encrypted password, then they should match.

PHP has built in Options to do that, look at [Creating a Hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), and [Verifying a Hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

pseudo-code

- hashed password = hp
- plain text password = p
- seed (Random Number generated by server) = s
- hash algorithm (md5, sha1, sha256, ...) = hash

**Example *with* Seeded Hash**

```
hp = hash(p + s)
```

the order you set the seed is not important, as long you do it the same way every time, by Concatenate the password and seed

**Example *without* Seeded Hash**

```
hp = hash(p)
```

you will need to save the **hp** and **seed**, the p should NEVER be saved by the server, as Plain Text Passwords is a security issue.

C# Code Example:

```
    static public bool IsPasswordCorrect(string hp, string seed, string enteredPasword)
    {
        return (hp == Sha1(String.Concat(enteredPasword, seed)));
    }
```

this way you have no direct way to get the password from the database, and only the actual Client will have the Plaintext Password.

if you want a 2-way encryption algorithm, you will need to look at RSA, but it is way more complicated and requires a lot of knowledge to make secure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "fetch" the hash from the database, you just hash the given password (from a login attempt I assume) and match THAT hash against the password column of a database. if a match is found where the password column matches the hash that you just made AND the username is a match, then the password is valid.

Comment: This is not correct. `crypt` will add a random salt. Unless you pass the original hashed password into crypt the hashes will, in all likelihood not match.

Comment: this is properly the more secure and correct way of doing it, as your not retrieving userdata, depending on what SQL language that is used, alot of stuff can be done on the SQL server to validate passwords, doing it more resilient to sqlinjections and so on.

Comment: @Jim you are correct. Perhaps I should have mentioned that for crypt, this is only true if you control the salt that is used. The php documentation says "If not provided, the behaviour is defined by the algorithm implementation and can lead to unexpected results."

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, if i really get your explanations you mean i should hash the coming password from a user attempting to login and then compare the hash value with the one in DB 
EXAMple
$salt=//the bcrypt algorithms format, cost parameter and the salt goes here, thesame with the one use when registrian

$coming_pass= crypt( $password, $salt)

mysqli_query ( SELECT from user WHERE username= $username AND 
password= $coming_pass)